# Rotary Encoder Schematic Symbol

Tags: schematics, eaglecad

I want to create a part in Eagle for Bourns PEC16 series rotary encoder. I can follow online tutorials, but I'm not sure what the standard rotary encoder symbol looks like. Is there a diagram or specification I can follow to make the part more useful?

Comment: I've never seen one other than a circle with an 'E' in it on industrial machine control panel schematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any standard for this, no. You see various permutations on:

- A box with a circle in it and terminals coming out of the side
- A circle with terminals, maybe with a rotational arrow in it
- A box with multiple switches in it
- A box with the words "Rotary Encoder" written in it

The list goes on. So just draw something that says what it is. A rotary encoder isn't really that pictorial a device, hence most things say what it is either within it or next to it.